# How do I install Office 2003 SP 1 on a virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualization, microsoft-office

When I try to install the office 2003 SP 1 (or 2 or 3) on a Virtual PC (2007) instance (using XP as OS) I get the message that it cannot get installed because Office 2003 is not installed. But of course I have installed Office 2003!!

I thought this was a Virtual PC 2007 related problem but I got the exact same behavior when I used VM Server i.e. a totally different virtualization product. So it must have something to do with the SP.

Then I thought that I could solve it by installing office 2003 on the host of the virtual instance (as well) to "trick" the Office 2003 SP 1 installer. But of course that did not work either.

How do I solve this?

Kallis

Comment: Are you specifically trying to install SP1 instead of SP2 or SP3?

Answer (score 1):

Not an issue related to virtualization. It's a messed up machine config for some reason or another, try to reproduce with a clean VM would be the first step in isolating the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Repair the Office 2003 install first.

Comment: ...or even (if you havent already) uninstall Office, restart VM, and reinstall Office if possible.  In Control Panel check the 'show updates' box to view Windows and Office updates.